# Iterating over a short, fixed list of strings

Tags: c++, c++20

What's the most efficient/elegant/idiomatic way in C++ to iterate over a short list of literal strings, where all the elements are known in advance? It can be done with vector:

```
for (auto color: std::vector<const char*>{"red", "green", "blue"})
    puts(color);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `for (auto color: {"red", "green", "blue"})` should be enough.

Comment: Plus one. Some `const`s and `&`s might be optimal but the question is important and relevant as it is.

Comment: I would not use std::vector I would use : `static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 3> colors {"red", "green", "blue" }; 
for (const auto color : colors) { std::cout << color;}`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Agree with using `constexpr` array of `string_view`. With `using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;`, you can express that as, `for (const auto color: {"red"sv, "green"sv, "blue"sv})`. [Godbolt link.](https://godbolt.org/z/4Taccz7rq)

Comment: @Davislor Yup better for a one liner. I assumed that if you make an array it might make an appearance somewhere else in the code ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Right, you’d want to declare a `constexpr` array instead of writing it inline once it gets much larger, or is used more than once.