# Parameter corresponding to function call with braced literal list

Tags: c++, c++20

As per a comment on [Iterating over a short, fixed list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76554088/iterating-over-a-short-fixed-list-of-strings) it turns out that in modern C++ you can write:

```
for (auto color: {"red", "green", "blue"})
```

Can you do something similar with a function call, and if so, what is the corresponding parameter declaration syntax? In other words,

```
void foo( /* ... */ )

foo({"red", "green", "blue"});
```

What should be substituted for the `...`?

Comment: One suitable parameter is a [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) since c++-20. Also avoid copies while iterating: `for (const auto& color: {"red", "green", "blue"})` is better.

Comment: The answer to this question is obvious if you can understand why comments work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative with a parameter pack and a fold expression:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class... Args>
void foo(Args&&...args) {
    (..., (std::cout << std::forward<Args>(args) << ' '));
}

int main() {
    foo("red", "green", "blue");
}
```

Comment: This is the most idiomatic c++20 solution IMHO. Brilliant @Ted

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks! I was thinking of folding over `&&` instead of folding over `,` to short-circuit in case of errors printing, but ... that seemed a little bit over the top :-)

Comment: I'd love to see the OP properly editing and enhancing their original question, which seems to be the appropriate target for answers. I am fine with enough reopening votes here, but some more work from OP's side still should be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a function template :

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
void foo(const std::string_view(&strings)[N])
{
    for (const auto string : strings)
    {
        std::cout << string << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo({ "red","green","blue" });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  The usual way is to declare `foo` as taking an `initializer_list`, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

void foo (std::initializer_list <std::string> il)
{
    for (const auto &s : il)
        std::cout << s << " ";
}

int main()
{
    foo ({"red", "green", "blue"});
}
```

Note that, for example, `std::vector` has just such a constructor and that all objects in the list must be of the same type.